# Finding the sum of a sequence of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

$$1/1(2) - 1/3(2^3) + 1/5(2^5) - 1/7(2^7)$$
This is equal to
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1/2)^{2n+1}(-1)^n/(2n+1)$$
Differentiating this leads to:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1/4)^n$$
Which is equal to $4/5$

Thus, the sum of the original series is equal to:
$$\int4/5dx = 4x/5$$

Could some one please confirm that my logic makes sense, specifically when I bring up the point of differentiating the series?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}%
\pars{\half}^{2n+1}\pars{-1}^{n}/\pars{2n+1}}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{2n+1}\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{x^{2} \over 4\phantom{^{2}}}}^{n}\,\dd x
=\half\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 - \pars{-x^{2}/4}}
=\int_{0}^{1/2}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}=\color{#66f}{\large\arctan\pars{\half}}
\\[3mm]&\approx {\tt 0.4636}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

No, partly because your answer contains a variable when it should be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The original series did not have $x$ anywhere in it, so why should its sum be a function of $x$?

You kinda had the right idea regarding differentiating a series.

Let $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. Then, $f'(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n} = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Since $f(0) = 0$, we have $f(t) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$ (which I'll let you evaluate).

Then, your desired sum is simply $f(\tfrac{1}{2})$.